# linux output grep an internal ip by hostname

Tags: linux, bash, shell

my question concerning a linux output :
using `gcloud` to list my vm instances :

```
HOSTNAME="chef-production2-doctor-simulator01"
gcloud compute instances list |grep $HOSTNAME
chef-production2-doctor-simulator01 us-central1-b n1-standard-1                         10.128.0.2  x.x.x.x   RUNNING
```

how can I grep the internal ip and output it to a bash variable?

```
INTERNAL_IP="$(gcloud compute instances list |grep $HOSTNAME)"
```

Comment: thanks @avivb but that wasn't the question

Comment: The question is not very clear, please give the output and what do you want to achieve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The popular tools for selecting a column are: `cut`, `sed` and `awk`. And of course, `perl`.

`awk` often is the shortest solution, but you will have to learn it's syntax.

```
gcloud compute instances list | \
awk '/chef-production2-doctor-simulator01/ { print $2 }'
```

may be what you are looking for. You may need to be explicit about *separators*. It's hard to tell which separators were used in the example you showed above.

Comment: Thanks, can you edit your answer if the hostname is in a variable $HOSTNAME ?

Comment: and placing the response in a variable

Comment: You should do that part to improve your shell scripting skills. E.g. how to escape the `$` in the `awk` command when using double quotes instead of single quotes. You need to figure out the indexing/separators anyway - I cannot test this on your computer!

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like thie:

```
var INTERNAL_IP="$(gcloud compute instances list | grep chef-production2-doctor-simulator01 | tr -s "  " | cut -d ' ' -f4)"
```

The tr -s "  " deletes all double spaces
The cut -d ' ' -f4 cuts out the ip

or as anony mentioned (which is better):

```
var INTERNAL_IP="$(gcloud compute instances list | awk '/chef-production2-doctor-simulator01/ { print $4 }'")
```